# how to upload image to imageproxy . from local

Tags: image, file-upload, cloud

I want to upload image directly to imageProxy. using graphql .

i follw this tutorial which is using which is using **Google Cloud Storage** but i want to upload  here . https://imgproxy.net/

is it possible. if some one know please guide  .
like this ...sample :
https://www.tomray.dev/google-cloud-file-uploads

I want to upload image directly to imageProxy.

Comment: ????????????????????????????????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.